# How to provide a dependency with @SessionScope and @ActivityScope using Dagger 2.10 Android Injector?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Suppose you have an application where user logs in on the first screen and, from that moment on, you have access to an `User` object. I would like to provide this dependency under a `@SessionScope` - it means, when user logs out, all dependencies provided through a component annotated as `@SessionScope` would die.

Despite the dependencies provides via `@SessionScope` I would like to have dependencies provided via `@ActivityScope`, an `ActivityPresenter` for instance and, of course, I would have to provide dependencies from `@SessionScope` and `@ActivityScope` together to an `Activity` consumer class.

**What is the best to do it using Dagger 2 new `AndroidInjector` feature?**

So far I'm able to provide dependencies under `@ActivityScope` like shown below:

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ActivityScope

@Module
abstract class ActivitiesBuilder {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(HomepageModule::class, FacebookModule::class))
    abstract fun providesHomepageViewImpl(): HomepageViewImpl

}

@Module
abstract class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provides (application: Application) : Context = application

}

@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = arrayOf(
                AndroidInjectionModule::class,
                ActivitiesBuilder::class,
                AppModule::class
        )
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()

}

class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> = DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Tutorial

1. Create a custom scope named `@SessionScope`;
2. Create a class named as `SessionActivityBinding`:

   - add a method that will bind the activity sub component that will be provided under session scope - further details on this implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/edsilfer/proof-of-concepts/tree/master/android-dagger2/sample-configuration);
3. Create a subcomponent named `SessionComponent`:

   - annotate this subcomponent with the custom scope created on step 1;
   - create a `@Subcomponent.Builder` and add a method that will receive a `User` object as parameter;

     - annotate this method with `@BindsInstance`;
     - add this method `fun build(): SessionComponent` in order to allow the provision of this `SessionComponent` - this will be necessary in order to release this component when user loggs out;
   - add `SessionActivityBinding` class into the module array;
   - **[OPTIONAL]**: Add a `SessionModule` class to provide dependencies that should be provided under `@SessionScope`;
4. On `AppModule` add `SessionComponent` as a subcomponent;
5. Add the `AppModule` in the list of module's from `AppComponent`;
6. When user successfully authenticate into the system, and an User object is acquired, create an instance of `SessionComponent` that must remain live until user logs out;
7. Whenever user logs out, discard the old instance of `SessionComponent` like: `sessionComponent = null` - this will discard all dependencies provided under `@SessionScope`;
8. Whenever user logs in again, repeat the process from step 6;

Further details and examples can be found [here](https://github.com/edsilfer/proof-of-concepts/tree/master/android-dagger2/session-scope);

Comment: Can you give further explanation about how does `SessionActivityBinding` class looks like? the link you provided seems to provide too general information.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I've found [this dagger login example project](https://github.com/edsilfer/proof-of-concepts/tree/master/android-facebook-login) useful for further information about the session concept, thanks to this answer.